# Generate Magento URL with secret key (nonce)

Tags: magento, selenium

I am trying to implement Selenium testing for Magento installation.

I stack at very beginning when I need to open specific URL in the Admin Section for Custom Module. Magento nonce is on and this parameter can not be changed.

To keep this more simple, I just need a URL like this:
http://mag.local/index.php/mymodule/mycontroller/index/key/e9310760d8bb9451e41e21105a87e874/

With following code I can receive
mag.local/mymodule/mycontroller/index/key/**another_nonce**/, which as you can imagine does not work.

```
$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('mymodule/mycontroller/index');
```

My config:

```
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mymodule_mycontroller before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Mycontroller</mymodule_mycontroller>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
        <mycontroller_route>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mymodule_Mycontroller</module>
                <frontName>mycontroller</frontName>
            </args>
        </mycontroller_route>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Well, one option is to disable the Use Secret Keys config setting in your test case using `Mage_Core_model_Config::setNode()`.

Comment: benmarks, thanks for your response, but this is actually not what I need. Looks like magento will generate right nonce for me. I am struggling with generating URL with 4 parts: index.php, mymodule, mycontroller and myaction. I can path only 3 parts into getUrl(). I feel that I missing something very obvious.

Comment: I'm not understanding your issue. Your Selenium script should be simulating access to the URL to be tested via the nonce OR you are assuming it's ok and not bother testing it.

Comment: Also: why are you both adding an additional frontname to the Admin router *and* adding your module controllers under the adminhtml frontname? Generally it's one or the other, with the latter being the conventionally-appropriate way to do it since CE 1.3.

Comment: @benmarks Yes, I need generate URL with nonce. Option with turning off nonce is not convenient for me at this time. Plus Magento already has functionality for generating URLs with nonce.

Comment: I am confused because redirect in Controller $this->_redirect('*/*/index'); gives right URL, but I can't get same URL with getUrl(). As for for additional frontname, I am new to Magento and don't know why it has been built in that way. I suppose it's index.php(as Admin identifier)/MODULE/CONTROLLER/ACTION. I can post my config if that will help. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The content of your `//modules` XPath is sufficient to add your module's *`controllers`* directory to the list of directories under the adminhtml module's frontname - meaning that if adminhtml frontname is set to "admin", URL to your module will be `site.com/index.php/admin/[controller file]/[action]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('route/path/here', array('another' => 'route_param'));
```

This should generate the super secret route parameter.

Reference: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited